# How do I pass date information to CVCalendar for display?

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I can't work out (and it's not clear from the documentation) how to provide information to CVCalendar so that it can decide whether to display a dot for a given date. Also, how do I display text information relevant to the selected date?

CVCalendar comes with methods for choosing whether to display a dot on a given date and to carry out an action for when the date is selected but doesn't tell you how to actually pass that information to the calendar. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: FYI - It's fine to post a question and your own answer. However, the question must conform to all of the normal standards for a good, valid question on stack overflow just as it would if you weren't providing your own answer. As written, your question doesn't follow any of the rules. It's not even a question. Write it like you want other people to help you answer it.

Comment: No problem, I've updated the question. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most elegant way I could come up with to deal with this was to use a dictionary so that the calendar can look the date up in the dictionary rather than eg iterating over dates in an array

```
var datesDictionary:[String:String] = ["5 November, 2016":"First item","9 November, 2016":"Second item","20 November, 2016":"Third item"]
```

Full code below. You'll need to set up views and delegates in storyboard as per [The documentation](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) as well as a UITextView (dayTextView) in your main viewcontroller

```
import UIKit
import CVCalendar

class ViewController: UIViewController,CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate,CVCalendarViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuView: CVCalendarMenuView!
    @IBOutlet weak var calendarView: CVCalendarView!
    @IBOutlet var dayTextView:UITextView!

    var datesDictionary:[String:String] = ["5 November, 2016":"Service","9 November, 2016":"Change Oil","20 November, 2016":"Check brakes"]

    func dotMarker(shouldShowOnDayView dayView: DayView) -> Bool{
        // Look up date in dictionary
        if(datesDictionary[dayView.date.commonDescription] != nil){
            return true // date is in the array so draw a dot
        }
        return false
    }
    func dotMarker(colorOnDayView dayView: DayView) -> [UIColor]{
        return [UIColor.black]
    }

    func didSelectDayView(_ dayView: DayView, animationDidFinish: Bool){

        dayTextView.text = ""
        // Look up date in dictionary
        if(datesDictionary[dayView.date.commonDescription] != nil){
            dayTextView.text = datesDictionary[dayView.date.commonDescription] // day is in the dictionary - wrote the corresponding text to dayTextView
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        menuView.commitMenuViewUpdate()
        calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
    }

    func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode{
        return .monthView
    }
    func firstWeekday() -> Weekday{
        return .monday
    }
}
```

Comment: Am using Same CVcalendarDelegate. But in that, delegate method(didselectDayView) is not getting called. Whats may be the problem.